# How do you take a row back into it's Model counterpart in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Scenario: I have a generator that is returning each of my users as single row. I need to update it, ideally with Eloquent, and not another raw query.

The recommended method of an update, which won't work for me in my scenario:

```
$user = User::whereId($id);
$user->name = "John Smith";
$user->save()
```

I've also been told to use `Model::update($id, $attributes])` but that won't work in my case since some of my attributes are not listed as fillable.

How can I take a single record and convert that back into it's model counterpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `save()` method in [laravel](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L1449) you will see there is a property called `exists`. All you need to do to convert a row back into the record is tell the model that it already exists and it will attempt an update instead of an insert.

Example:

```
$user = app(User::class);
$user->exists = true;
$user->id = 1;
$user->name = "John Smith";
$user->save();
```

And there you have it. The model knows intelligently that it should do an update instead of an insert.